# Не выполняется sql через php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Программисты, помогите, пожалуйста. Не знаю почему, но в таблицу не добавляется запись. Ошибки не выводяться. Переменная sha_password, которая не показана здесь, имеется.

```
$nameDb = "id6118892_about_users";
    $host = "localhost";
    $password = "---";
    $userName = "id6118892_hasker_kek";

    $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $userName, $password);
    if(!connection) {
        die("Ошибка соединения." . mysqli_error());
    }
    mysqli_select_db($nameDb);

    $query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `users` (telephone,password,about_user) VALUES ('$telephone','$sha_password','info')");

    if(!query) {
        die("Неверный запрос.");
    }
```

Comment: перед $query; напишите echo "INSERT INTO `users` (telephone,password,about_user) VALUES ('$telephone','$sha_password','info')"; и покажите вывод

Comment: @madfan41k, INSERT INTO `users` (telephone,password,about_user) VALUES ('11111111111','807ae5f38db47bff8b09b37ad803cb10ef5147567a89a33a66bb3282df4ad966','info').          Если делать через var_dump($query), то выводится NULL.

Comment: Надо открывать руководство по `mysqli` и курить список аргументов, но это ж ведь сложно.

Comment: а как вы прокомментируете вашу строку if(!connection) ?
может там все-таки  if(!$connection) ?

Comment: и включите вывод ошибок
ini_set("display_errors",1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @madfan41k, конечно же $connection вместо connection;